# echo psc | tmadmin - How does it work as individual?

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, echo, tuxedo

I am using the following command:

```
echo psc | tmadmin
```

Its output is like:

> seFreeSusp00 seFreeSusp00 julRSecur  JUL      146 xyz       0 AVAIL
>
> seExpireUse+ seExpireUse+ julRSecur  JUL      146 xyz       0 AVAIL

I understand that it returns the list of the service in tuxedo environment.

My Question is - what does the the individual command do? I mean, there is a pipe command used. output of first is the input of second.
So how does this command work individually?

Comment: Not programming related - move to superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: I usually use it in my shell script, but never though of individual output :( @KevinDTimm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmadmin is reading its commands from the stdin.  So when you pipe in the string "psc" that is telling tmadmin to run the psc command